# Redis - Check if an email is already in use

Tags: redis

In my application I store users as `user:n` where n is a unique ID.

When a new user is created I increment a global variable such as `user_count` and use that ID as `user:n`.

But, I have an issue where I need to ensure an email is not already in use. I've done some reading around and the only way I can see how to do this is to:

1) Loop through the users. But, I am not keen on this solution as it could cause slower performance right?

2) Create a lookup that contains a list of email addresses used.

Both solutions seem a bit strange to me as I come from an SQL background.

Are these the only options available? I also have to do the same check for usernames too.

Comment: are you using redis as primary database for your application or is it being used as cache?

Comment: @AbhijitGaikwad The primary database. I use AOF to keep backups of the data. The nature of the application requires very fast datastore so we went with Redis. I know generally this is frowned upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Sets:

On registration: `sadd taken_emails "john@example.com"`

And testing with: `sismember taken_emails "bob@exmaple.com"`

Note that you have a possible race-condition where two users try to use the same email at the same time, both test and get "free" and then both register with it. You could use a [lock](http://redis.io/topics/distlock) to make sure they don't both get it, or make the registration operation atomic with either `WATCH/MULTI/EXEC` or with a lua script.